# Difficult integral : $ \int_{D} \sum_{i=1}^K e^{-\frac{\|X-x_j\|_2^2}{2r^2}} \mathrm d^2X $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Consider a matrix $X = (x_i,x_j)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $0<x_k<1, \forall k$. Then,
> let $D$ be a disk of radius $r$ centered at each $x_i$. Solve: $$   \frac{1}{2K\pi r^2} \int_{D} \sum_{i=1}^K e^{-\frac{\|X-x_j\|_2^2}{2r^2}} \mathrm d^2X $$

First, since we are integrating disks each of the same size at different points, i assume that each integral should be equal, right? Therefore, we can remove the summation
\begin{align*}
     &= \frac{1}{2\pi r^2} \int_{D}  e^{-\frac{\|X-x_j\|_2^2}{2r^2}}\mathrm d^2X ~~~\\
  & = \frac{1}{2\pi r^2} \int_{{D}} e^{-\frac{(x_1 - x_{j1})^2 + (x_2 - x_{j2})^2}{2r^2}} \mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2\\
&=  \frac{1}{2\pi r^2}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r \exp\left(- \frac{p^2\sin^2(\theta)+p^2\cos^2(\theta)}{2r^2}\right)r \mathrm d\theta \mathrm dp\\
&= \frac{r}{2\pi}\left(1-e^{\frac{-2\pi^2}{r^2} } \right) 
  \end{align*}

However, the answer is not correct. I assume i made a mistake removing the summation!

Comment: There is incoherence in your notations. $x_k$ is sometimes a real coordinate and sometimes a center of a disk in $\mathbb R^2$. Can you fix that and review your question?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yeah, I want to integrate a disk centred around each $x_k = (a,b)$ coordinate. Is this not right?